# Regarding post text filtering

Tags: filters

What does this statement actually do?

```
$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
```

It follows only these ones:

```
$text = get_the_content('');

$text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
```

What filter(s) is applied here?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please add some more explanation to it.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to show the post content, within the loop, is to use:

```
the_content();
```

that will **echo** the output, not **return** it like `get_the_content()`.

But since you want to assign it to the `$text` variable, you use:

```
$text = get_the_content('');
```

but then the `the_content` output filter is not applied.

That's the reason why you have this line:

```
$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
```

because it will filter `$text` through all the callbacks registered to the `the_content` filter.

You can always learn a lot from reading the source directly. The `the_content()` function is [defined](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L156) as:

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
        $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
        $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
        echo $content;
}
```

You can check all the callbacks registered to the `the_content` filter with:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function(){
   printf( '<h3>Debug:</h3><pre>%s</pre>', 
            print_r( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['the_content'], TRUE ) ); 
});
```

This will give you output at the bottom of your page, similar to this:

```
<h3>Debug:</h3>
<pre>Array
( 
    [10] => Array
        (
            [wptexturize] => Array
                (
                    [function] => wptexturize
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [convert_smilies] => Array
                (
                    [function] => convert_smilies
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [convert_chars] => Array
                (
                    [function] => convert_chars
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [wpautop] => Array
                (
                    [function] => wpautop
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [shortcode_unautop] => Array
                (
                    [function] => shortcode_unautop
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [prepend_attachment] => Array
                (
                    [function] => prepend_attachment
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [capital_P_dangit] => Array
                (
                    [function] => capital_P_dangit
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [do_shortcode] => Array
                (
                    [function] => do_shortcode
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

where the array key numbers are the filter *priorites*.